# Show tooltip on load with google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, tooltip

I'm trying to use the `tooltip.trigger = 'selection'` and `setSelection([{row:4,column:null}])`, but the tooltip doesn't show up automatically. Only when you click on another tooltip.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wt2afgxg/) showing the problem.

Any ideas what I can try?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you should use a `google.visualization.events.addListener` instead of just setting the selection, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/wt2afgxg/3/) but that didn't solve the problem either. Looks like a bug that it doesn't load the tooltip if you set the selection before the user has interacted with the chart.. Maybe you could simulate a mouseclick?

Comment: @HenrikAronsson Thanks, that does seem like the smarter way to call it. I've opened up an issue on the github issue tracker for google visualization issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using annotations. Though I would definitely be interested in the tooltips if anyone figures out a way.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wt2afgxg/2/)

```
var gmapData = [[{"label":"Date","type":"date"},"One",{"role":"annotation","type":"string"},"Two",{"role":"annotation","type":"string"},"Three",{"role":"annotation","type":"string"}],["Date(2012, 3, 26)",412,null,278,null,149,null],["Date(2012, 3, 27)",410,null,272,null,147,null],["Date(2012, 3, 30)",414,null,280,null,146,null],["Date(2012, 4, 1)",406,"$406",268,"$268",141,"$141"]];

    drawChart();

    function drawChart() {
        var data = window.data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(gmapData);

        // apply a tooltip formatting
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '$#,###'});
        var cols = (gmapData[0].length-1) / 2;
        x = cols;
        // apply a tooltip formatting
        while ((--x) >= 0)
            formatter.format(data, x*2+1);

        var options = {
            title: 'Number Watch',
            legend: { position: 'bottom' },
            interpolateNulls: true,
            curveType: 'function',
            selectionMode: 'single',
            tooltip: {trigger: 'focus'},
            focusTarget: 'category',
            annotations: {
                textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 18
                }
            },
            vAxis: {format: '$#,###'},
            width: 400,
            height: 300
        };

        var chart = window.chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('num_watch'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

---

[github issue reply:](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2001#issuecomment-114127142)

> Hi,
>
> This is a known bug with focusTarget: 'category'. That particular option uses the mouse position as a signal for how to position the tooltip, and so programmatic selection won't trigger a tooltip to display.
>
> To circumvent this issue, you could use multiple selection on the first load. Here's an example of this, along with a reset that changes the focusTarget back to 'category' at the first opportunity: http://jsfiddle.net/b1kt6mrL/

jsfiddle:

```
// ..... all previous code, not with the annotations
chart.draw(data, options);
chart.setSelection([{row:4, column:1}, {row:4, column:2}, {row:4, column:3}]);

google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function() {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    options.focusTarget = 'category';
    options.selectionMode = 'single';
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
        chart.setSelection(selection);
    });
    chart.draw(data, options);
});
```